# Capistrano with a nested rails directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, capistrano

My Ruby on Rails application is not the root file of my git repository.  Is there a variable that I can set so that Capistrano knows what directory to run rake when I ask it to run migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it by overriding the `deploy:migrate` recipe like this:

```
namespace :deploy do
   task :migrate do
     run "cd /path/to/rails/root; rake RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} #{migrate_env} db:migrate"
   end
end
```

Comment: I received a "could not find rakefile" error after trying this.  Inserting "pwd;" after the change directory directive and recieved the home path for the user capistrano was signing in with...

Comment: Also, what is the "migrate_env" variable?

Comment: found the example based on the capistrano wiki (https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks) 
AFAIK migrate_env used when you wish to use something different than your RAILS_ENV when running your migrations.

Comment: if rake can't find your rakefile by default, you can use rake -f /path/to/rakefile

Comment: Note:  I had to create a specific gemset for the application.

Comment: Got you, you better use the rvm/capistrano gem to be sure. with that you can specify the gemset and ruby version to use: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano